# Updating image in IE11 not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, internet-explorer-11

I am having an application to upload multiple image using a browse button. I am calling a servlet for performing these operations to store in the databse,retreive it and store it in the database. Below is my code of the JSP page :

```
<%if(imageVO != null)
        {%>


                            <TR>
                    <% if (!imageVO.getImage1().equals("")) {
                    Filetype = (imageVO.getImage1().substring(imageVO.getImage1().lastIndexOf(".")+1,imageVO.getImage1().length())).toLowerCase().trim();
                    System.out.println("Inside If for Image1-=========="+Filetype);
                      if("jpg".equalsIgnoreCase(Filetype) || "jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(Filetype)){ System.out.println("Inside If222222 for Image1-=========="+Filetype+"Ireq"+iReq+"Program type"+prog); %>
                    <TD align="left" colspan="4"><br/><IMG border="0"  
                        src="/servletpath/Servlet?ireq=<%=iReq%>&iseq=1&targetAction=retrievePic&tabVal=0&ProgramType=<%=prog%>"
                        width="200" height="150" id="image11" name="image11"><INPUT type="hidden" name="imageSequence1" id="imageSequence1" value="1"></TD>
                    <%} else {
                        System.out.println("Inside else Image11111"); %>
                    <TD align="center" colspan="4" width="200" height="70"><a href="/servletpath/Servlet?ireq=<%=iReq%>&iseq=1&targetAction=retrievePic&tabVal=0&ProgramType=<%=prog%>" id="image11" name="image11"> <%=imageVO.getImage1() %> </a><INPUT type="hidden" name="imageSequence1" id="imageSequence1" value="1"></TD>
               <% request.getSession().setAttribute("browseType",null);
                    request.getSession().removeAttribute("browseType");
                    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("browseType")!=null)
                    System.out.println("Value of Remove Browse type attr removed 333======="+(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("browseType"));} }  %>               

                    <%  if (!imageVO.getImage2().equals("")) { 
                     Filetype = (imageVO.getImage2().substring(imageVO.getImage2().lastIndexOf(".")+1,imageVO.getImage2().length())).toLowerCase().trim();
                     if("jpg".equalsIgnoreCase(Filetype) || "jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(Filetype)){ %>          
                    <TD align="left" colspan="3"><br/><IMG border="0"
                        src="/servletpath/Servlet?ireq=<%=iReq%>&iseq=2&targetAction=retrievePic&tabVal=0&ProgramType=<%=prog%>"
                        width="200" height="150" name="image22" id="image22"><INPUT type="hidden" name="imageSequence2" id="imageSequence2" value="2"></TD>
                    <%} else {
                        System.out.println("Inside else Image2222222222"); %>   
                         <TD align="center" colspan="3" width="200" height="70"><a href="/servletpath/Servlet?ireq=<%=iReq%>&iseq=2&targetAction=retrievePic&tabVal=0&ProgramType=<%=prog%>" name="image22" id="image22" > <%=imageVO.getImage2() %> </a><INPUT type="hidden" name="imageSequence2" id="imageSequence2" value="2"></TD>
     <%request.getSession().setAttribute("browseType",null);
                         request.getSession().removeAttribute("browseType");
                         if(request.getSession().getAttribute("browseType")!=null)
                         System.out.println("Value of Remove Browse type attr removed 333======="+(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("browseType"));} }  %>      


                </TR>
            <%} %>
```

This is the part of the code where the thumbnail of the image will be displayed retrieving from the database.For displaying the the servlet in the src tag should be called.
When I upload an image for the first time, the flow works correctly and the servlet for retrieve is getting called correctly. When I try to update the image in the same place,the flow is going correctly(image is updated in the DB) but the retreive pic servlet is not getting called. This issue is occurring only in IE11. In other lower versions of IE it is working correctly.
Is there any tags/code not supported in IE11. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the cache problem. I changed the url of the servlet with the timestamp so that the servlet would be called everytime for the new image. It worked .

```
ServletPath/Servlet?ireq=<%=iReq%>&iseq=1&targetAction=retrievePic&tabVal=0&ProgramType=<%=prog%>&time=<%=java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()%>"
```